# PCB manufacturing process

Tags: pcb-fabrication, etching

What process can I use for PCB etching? What chemical compositions required along with etching time, reuseability of the solvent, inks to be used so that copper layer of the drawing area is unaffected?

I have tried etching with ferric chloride method with 100 g of FeCl<sub>3</sub> and 200 ml of water. It works but took me around one hour and I found FeCl<sub>3</sub> is not environmentally friendly. Then I use HCl and H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub> of 36% and 30% concentration respectively. Diluting H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub> to 3, 6 and 9% and mixing in 1:1 and 1:2 ratio has removed the ink layer as well. I have used screen printing method and ink as well. I am doing so in order to build a small PCB manufacturing company.

I need any other information about PCB manufacturing in detail as possible.

Comment: You find a local fab house and let them do it. Saves you a lot of mess and  potential harm

Comment: @rs04 - Thanks for adding new information in comments. As I mentioned in my earlier (now obsolete and therefore deleted) comment, updates need to be made as an *edit* to the original question (all relevant information should be in the question) so I have moved your updates into the question and deleted those (now obsolete) comments.

Comment: I once had a "summer job" at a PCB manufacturer where I rotated through most of the departments. Just about every step of the way involves hazardous materials and there's really no way around that for the kinds of boards most people want. You need to learn proper disposal. While you could just apply copper tape to bare boards (or buy a 3D printer that handles copper), that doesn't suffice for many designs.

Comment: One of our suppliers here in Canada had installed in excess of $2m (then dollars, figure x3-5 now) of equipment for environmental treatment, but was still sued by his landlord for millions when they moved (again x3-5 now maybe) for  cleanup. Environmental protection regulations have not gotten less stringent. This stuff does not scale well between doing it on the q.t. in your kitchen and having an operation with many, many employees. You can get help from your prospective equipment suppliers. Dry film photoresist is popular. Screen printing is simple to do, but suitable only for crude PCBs.

Comment: Heat ferric chloride somewhat.|| Peroxide is excellent once you get dilution right. Some etch resists may be more soluble than others.

Comment: I have used HCl and H2O2 but it etched away ink as well. I have used screen printing ink. Do i have to use special kind of ink?